# Error "The type or namespace name 'xxx' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls'"

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I have finally updated Microsoft.Toolkit from 7.0 to 7.1. The debug version of an app works fine. When I build the app's package with .Net Native, I get the following errors:

```
2>  E:\...\My App\obj\x64\Release\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs(701,78,701,82): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>  E:\...\My App\obj\x64\Release\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs(705,78,705,83): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Input' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>  E:\...\My App\obj\x64\Release\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs(711,78,711,83): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Could anyone shed some light on the possible cause of these errors?  Everything worked fine before the update.